# Search more than one id (UUID)

Tags: solr, solr4

My Id field is declared as follows

```
 <field name="VersionId" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

and I query it using

```
 http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=VersionId:5d4cb2a7-198b-4e26-a003-3b0388e35820
```

I want to search more than one UUID.
What is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the id is fixed you can use filter query to search multiple ids would be best for performance with [Filter Cache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) as well e.g.

```
fq=VersionId:(5d4cb2a7-198b-4e26-a003-3b0388e35820 OR 5d4cb2a7-198b-4e26-a003-3b0388e35820 OR 5d4cb2a7-198b-4e26-a003-3b0388e35820 .....)
```

Comment: What is the difference between using it with q=? performance?

Comment: Query with are search queries which would evaluate scores. Filter queries are constant scoring filter queries and can make use of filter cache if tuned properly can improve performance very much